# Mathematica fails to load welcome screen: "Authentication Required"

Tags: bugs, crash, databaselink

### Problem

When I open Mathematica 12.1.0 on windows 10, I get an "Authentication Required" window during the splash screen. The auth window has no input or buttons, and the text in the window is:

```
    FormControl[Null,
    FormObject[{Username-><|Interpreter->String, Label->Username,
        Control->(AuthenticationDialogDump`formField[##1, BoxID->
            AuthenticationDialogDump`$AuthenticationBoxID]&),
        Input->|>, Password-><|Interpreter->String, Label->Password,
        Control->(AuthenticationDialogDump`formField[##1, BoxID->
            AuthenticationDialogDump`$AuthenticationBoxID,
            FieldMasked->True]&),
        Input->|>},AppearanceRules->Automatic]]
```

I believe (but cannot prove) that this is a result of me creating and partially completing a database connection with the DatabaseLink package.

I cannot actually interact with Mathematica, because the program crashes/closes when I close the authentication window.  The welcome screen is never displayed.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

### Attempted solutions so far

- Reinstall the program

  - Error persists
- Deleted an .m file in %appdata% which contained an OpenSQLConnection command corresponding to my partial database link

  - Error persists
- Searched registry for entries related to my database link

  - Nothing found
- Searched the entire hard drive for any .m files modified since the last time I successfully opened mathematica

  - Nothing found

Comment: I would think contacting Wolfram would be the right thing.

Comment: Just a hunch: maybe the "Controlled Folder Access" of Windows 10 interferes. Could you check in the corresponding Windows security settings whether Mathematica (kernel or notebook) has been blocked (and if so grant the required permissions)?